# Is there any Disadvantage of increasing alpha in Triplet loss?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to make a generalised feature extractor, which can also classify a new class as an unknown class in the model.
Is there any good Technique available other than distance based matrix ?

Currently I am using Triplet loss in which my Triplet training loss becomes +0.00000 at certain points due to smaller alpha value.
So Is there any Disadvantage of increasing alpha to drastic amount like 100 ?

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this may make the learning to hard for your model, and thus he may not be able to learn anything. In fact, you need to normalize you features before feeding them to the triplet loss, in that case you only need to use a value of the same order as 1

Comment: Input has to be normalized or between 0 to 1, but after forward prop of certain layers the neuron values become high (not between 0 to 1) and that's why it penalise any high valued triplet loss (alpha). So we have to convert final embedding layer output between 0 to 1 (not even between -1 to 1, because of distance based learning) without feature loss.